# Gather data with request on python

Tags: python, json, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
}

params = (
    ('LeagueID', '00'),
    ('Season', '2017-18'),
    ('TeamID', '1610612757'),
)

data = requests.get('https://www.nba.com/stats/players/cut/',
                    headers=headers, params=params).json()
pprint(data)
columns=data['resultSets'][0]['headers']
for result_set in data['resultSets']:
    print("Result set", result_set['name'])
    for item in result_set['rowSet']:
        pprint(dict(zip(result_set['headers'], item)))
```

I try to run this code, but I systematically have this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My goal is to get the data from the table on the link basically. I succeeded with the API, but there aren't all the information I need for my analysis. This is why I prefer to do it by "Scraping" the nba.com site.

Comment: The URL `https://www.nba.com/stats/players/cut/` doesn't appear to return JSON data.

Comment: Is pprint(data) printing anything?

Comment: **This is why I prefer to do it by "Scrapping" the nba.com site** then why are you trying to convert the `HTML` into `JSON`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing some of the headers parameters. Also, I don't think the team id query works right. You also need to use `url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/synergyplaytypes'`

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

headers = {
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'stats.nba.com',
'Origin': 'https://www.nba.com',
'Referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", "\"Not;A\\Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Mobile Safari/537.36',
'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
'x-nba-stats-token': 'true'
}

params = {'LeagueID': '00',
'PerMode': 'PerGame',
'PlayType': 'Cut',
'PlayerOrTeam': 'P',
'SeasonType': 'Regular Season',
'SeasonYear': '2020-21',
'TypeGrouping': 'offensive'}

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/synergyplaytypes'
data = requests.get(url,
                    headers=headers, params=params).json()
pprint(data)
columns=data['resultSets'][0]['headers']
for result_set in data['resultSets']:
    print("Result set", result_set['name'])
    for item in result_set['rowSet']:
        pprint(dict(zip(result_set['headers'], item)))
```

**Output:**

```
...
{'EFG_PCT': 0.5,
 'FGA': 1.4,
 'FGM': 0.7,
 'FGMX': 0.7,
 'FG_PCT': 0.5,
 'FT_POSS_PCT': 0.1,
 'GP': 7,
 'PERCENTILE': 0.244,
 'PLAYER_ID': 1630214,
 'PLAYER_NAME': 'Xavier Tillman',
 'PLAY_TYPE': 'Cut',
 'PLUSONE_POSS_PCT': 0.1,
 'POSS': 1.4,
 'POSS_PCT': 0.192,
 'PPP': 1.1,
 'PTS': 1.6,
 'SCORE_POSS_PCT': 0.5,
 'SEASON_ID': '22020',
 'SF_POSS_PCT': 0.1,
 'TEAM_ABBREVIATION': 'MEM',
 'TEAM_ID': 1610612763,
 'TEAM_NAME': 'Memphis Grizzlies',
 'TOV_POSS_PCT': 0.0,
 'TYPE_GROUPING': 'Offensive'}
{'EFG_PCT': 0.444,
 'FGA': 1.0,
 'FGM': 0.6,
 'FGMX': 0.6,
 'FG_PCT': 0.444,
 'FT_POSS_PCT': 0.273,
 'GP': 9,
 'PERCENTILE': 0.044,
 'PLAYER_ID': 203939,
 'PLAYER_NAME': 'Dwight Powell',
 'PLAY_TYPE': 'Cut',
 'PLUSONE_POSS_PCT': 0.091,
 'POSS': 1.2,
 'POSS_PCT': 0.234,
 'PPP': 0.909,
 'PTS': 1.1,
 'SCORE_POSS_PCT': 0.455,
 'SEASON_ID': '22020',
 'SF_POSS_PCT': 0.273,
 'TEAM_ABBREVIATION': 'DAL',
 'TEAM_ID': 1610612742,
 'TEAM_NAME': 'Dallas Mavericks',
 'TOV_POSS_PCT': 0.0,
 'TYPE_GROUPING': 'Offensive'}
{'EFG_PCT': 0.333,
 'FGA': 1.3,
 'FGM': 0.9,
 'FGMX': 0.9,
 'FG_PCT': 0.333,
 'FT_POSS_PCT': 0.091,
 'GP': 7,
 'PERCENTILE': 0.0,
 'PLAYER_ID': 1629060,
 'PLAYER_NAME': 'Rui Hachimura',
 'PLAY_TYPE': 'Cut',
 'PLUSONE_POSS_PCT': 0.0,
 'POSS': 1.6,
 'POSS_PCT': 0.126,
 'PPP': 0.636,
 'PTS': 1.0,
 'SCORE_POSS_PCT': 0.364,
 'SEASON_ID': '22020',
 'SF_POSS_PCT': 0.091,
 'TEAM_ABBREVIATION': 'WAS',
 'TEAM_ID': 1610612764,
 'TEAM_NAME': 'Washington Wizards',
 'TOV_POSS_PCT': 0.091,
 'TYPE_GROUPING': 'Offensive'}
```

You can find all that info by opeing your Dev Tools and Inspect. You want to go to Network -> XHR, then search through there to see which request gets the data (you may need to reload the page after you open Dev Tools)

[image]

Then change it to Headers and you'll see the url:

[image]

and scroll down for the other other headers and params used. You likely don't need ALL of them, but there seems to be a few that are definitely needed. you can play around and see which one or ones are needed for the nba api.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for this quick answer. Indeed, there were a lot of things missing, but my question is : how did you find the good url / headers / param that you put ? Because I tried to inspect the site, but didn't find these informations. I couldn't find any generic tutorials on this. Anyway, thank you A LOT!

Comment: Ah ya. Don’t have a chance now, but I’ll show you when I get to my laptop to give you a detailed answer. But you can find it under the Dev Tools.

Comment: No problem! Take your time :) but thank you again!!

Comment: Thank you again, I tried to perform it on an another page with your method and it did work perfectly! Thank you very much
Sending you good vibes from France!

Answer (score 0):

You want to do web scraping on a html web page. But you are converting them to json in the requests you are making. Both are different. The link you have provided is not a rest API.

You can try using the following framework https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>Some<b>bad<i>HTML")
soup.find(text="bad")
```

You can refer to the documentation to more about this framework